# Powers of $m$-cycles are also $m$-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\sigma$ be the $m$-cycle $(1~2~...~m)$. Show that $\sigma^i$ is also an $m-$cycle if and only if $i$ is relatively prime to $m$.

I having some difficulty with this problem. Through experimenting with some simple cycles, I have seen a cycle "split" into a product of disjoint cycles when its length is not relatively prime to $i$, but I have no way of rigorously describing this "splitting." I guess my question is, how do distinguish between cycles and "split" cycles; and how could this help with solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

An $\;m\,-$ cycle $\;\sigma\;$ is an element of order $\;m\;$ in the *group* $\;S_m\;$ and as in any other group, we have that $\;\langle \sigma^k\rangle=\langle\sigma\rangle\iff (m,k)=1\;$ , so one direction is immediate...and the other one almost: if $\;(k,m)=d>1\;$ , then $\;\sigma^k\;$ has order *less* than $\;m\;$ so it can **not** be an $\;m\,-$ cycle.

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem comes before cyclic groups are discussed in any depth.

Comment: Really?? Then you people read group theory in a very different way I am used to.

Comment: Yeah...This problem comes from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, a book that is beginning to vex me. I don't think the text is organized nor presented well; although it does have a vast number of problems. I am thinking of switching to Hungerford or some other text. Any suggestions?

Comment: In general I think that D&F is a rather good book. If you're reading this yourself you can check Gallian, Hungerford, Aluffi, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the "immediate" direction. Could you explain how $\langle \sigma^k \rangle = \langle \sigma \rangle$ implies that $\sigma^k$ is an $m$-cycle?

Comment: @Lylypad That's due to the fact that in any group $\;G\;$, if we have an element of order $\;m\;$ in  it, say $\;x\in G\;$, then $\;x^k=1\iff (m,k)=1\;$ . This doesn't even have anything to see directly with cyclic groups or symmetric groups, but rather with powers of elements in groups. In this case, we need to now that an $\;m\,$- cycle in a symmetric group is in fact an element of order $\;m\;$ in that group. That's all.

Comment: I thought that if $x$ has order $m$, then $x^k = 1 \iff m \mid k$? I'm still confused. If $\sigma$ is an $m$-cycle then I know $|\sigma|=m$. I also know that the order of $\sigma^k$ is $\frac{m}{(m,k)}$. So if $(m,k)=1$ then $\sigma^k$ has order $m$. In particular, if $\sigma^k$ is a cycle then it must be an $m$-cycle. But I don't know how to show that $\sigma^k$ is even a cycle.